# i want to remove a substring from a link of strings in a column of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace

```
df_bucket['Uri'].str.replace('www.','')
```

these are the link in a dataframe:

```
'https://www.durbine.com.bd/Upload/vimg/20211104/N20211104044257_270256_Jgh3eI3dJo7Lv2GuGiWswwwW.jpg', 'https://www.durbine.com.bd/Upload/vimg/20211104/N20211104044808_280753_miGVs4defXAMXcmFM1XJwwwX.jpg'
```

but the result is:

```
'https://durbine.com.bd/Upload/vimg/20211104/N20211104044257_270256_Jgh3eI3dJo7Lv2GuGiWs.jpg', 'https://durbine.com.bd/Upload/vimg/20211104/N20211104044808_280753_miGVs4defXAMXcmFM1XJ.jpg'
```

it is also removing wwwX and wwwW from the last.

Comment: Hello, can you explain what you are ultimately trying to extract? Are you trying, for example, to get the substring `durbine` from the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `www.` with a *literal* dot, so turn off regex in your call to `str.replace`:

```py
df_bucket['Uri'].str.replace('www.', '', regex=False)
```

Or, if you want to use `str.replace` in default regex mode, then escape the dot with backslash:

```py
df_bucket['Uri'].str.replace('www\.', '')
```